# Rebuild element in jQuery vs. mass showing/hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a paginated table of data that I want to cache client-side and I'm trying to figure out how to most efficiently switch pages.

Would it be better to do:

A. Rebuild and replace the table via one modification to the DOM

```
var pageLength = 50;
var cache; //array of some objects from database

function changePage(index) {
    var $table = $("<table>");
    $.each(cache, function (i, row) {
        var $tr = $("<tr>");
        if (i < index || i > index + pageLength) $tr.hide();
        $tr.append($("<td>", { text: row.ID }));
        $tr.append($("<td>", { text: row.Name }));
        $table.append($tr);
    });
    $("#targetDiv").html($table);
}
```

or

B. Showing and hiding the rows after inserting into the DOM

```
function changePage(index) {
    var $table = $("#targetDiv table");
    $table.find("tr:visible").hide();
    $table.find("tr").each(function (i, row) {
        if (i > index && i < index + pageLength) $tr.show();
    });
}
```

I wrote something along the lines of the first one and ran it in Chrome vs IE8 and found IE was very noticeably slower, whereas Chrome had no problem.  Our standard is still IE7 unfortunately, so I'm trying to optimize in the likely event the JS engine in IE7 is worse performance-wise than IE8.

Comment: How many objects to you expect to be in the table at once? Or better said, what is the maximum number of objects expected to be in a single table?

Comment: It can vary, the example I'm working with is around 425

Comment: Showing and hiding will always be faster than DOM insertion, but if there is a lot of HTML, updating the DOM each time is sometimes a better idea to reduce initial page load time, so it depends? Using a document fragment and plain JS would speed the first function up considerably.

Comment: It's one of those situations where up until a certain point, one is better, then the other surpasses. I'd go with the replace since it will work with larger datasets just as fast as it will with smaller ones. Though, i'd suggest not looping through ALL rows just looking for index y-z, just loop through y-z.

Comment: Would it be a better idea to cache the data server-side and paginate by grabbing a smaller dataset to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a combination of both.

On load you would show page one (with a reference to your complete list stored somewhere).

When page two is requested you would populate it with page two data and hide page one.

When page two is requested another time it would already be populated so it would be a hide/show function.

This would best be handled by a class that knows which page is current, how many pages there could be, etc. Then when you could do some smart memory management where you can empty pages that are a certain number of pages away from the current page.

**But I would recommend using an existing solution**

There are MANY client side paging plugins, especially for jQuery.

- [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) is something I have used in the past and while it's a bit of a struggle to begin with it's highly extensible.
- Here is a [List of jQuery plugins](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/10/jquery-pagination-plugins.html) that google directed me to.

I would go with an existing solution and not try to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: Thanks! I've heard of DataTables before, but I'd never actually looked into it.  It's performing great in both IE and Chrome.